# Replacement for SocketUtils.findAvailableTcpPort()?

Tags: java, spring, sockets, spring-integration

The following initializes as socket with `spring-integration` on a dedicated port.

Goal is to give the application 2 minutes of time to run on that port, or fail is not successful. But the application start should *not* fail *directly* of that port is not free on startup!

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class SocketConfiguration {    
        @Value("${app.port}")
        private String port;
    
        @Bean
        public TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean tcpFactory() {
            CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> SocketUtils.findAvailableTcpPort(port, port)).get(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        }
}
```

Problem: `SocketUtils` is `@Deprecated` since Spring Framework 6.
What is a proper replacement for it?

The docs only state as an alternative:

> Instead of using SocketUtils to find an available local port for a server, it is recommended that you rely on a server's ability to start on a random port

Well, that's not what I want, neither can I use if, because I'm historically bound to that specific port!

Comment: If the `SocketUtils` method is working for you, why do you need to change it? A deprecation warning isn't a prohibition against using it; as long as you understand the consequences, it's not unreasonable to continue using a deprecated class/method as long as it is the best tool for your need.

Comment: That technique to find an available port is not reliable; it is best to set the port to 0 and let the OS choose the port; then use the port that the OS selected.

Comment: @GaryRussell well but due to legacy reasons I have to stick to that port.

Comment: @E-Riz the class is removed in Spring 6, so I'm forced to migrate.

Comment: If you have a fixed port....why do you use a utility method for finding available ports? Why don't you just use the fixed port and ditch `SocketUtils` completely?

Comment: Also this sounds like a hacky workaround to a different problem, because if you're running on a fixed port, why wouldn't it be free? Because the last instance didn't shutdown properly?

Comment: @Kayaman because instance-2 should warm up except for the socket port, while instance-1 is still running. Then when instance-1 is shut down, the port will be free.

Answer (score 9):

There is a `org.springframework.test.util.TestSocketUtils` instead. But as Gary said it is better to rely on operation system choice via `0` for port option. Although why would one select a random port in a production code...

To get a real selected port you can listen for a `TcpConnectionServerListeningEvent` which will bring for you that actual value.

Comment: The problem is that `TestSocketUtils` is not available in a non-test context, so in normal code. And I'm bound to use that fixed port due to legacy reasons...

Comment: That's exactly my point: no one uses a random port for the server in production code.

Comment: Except if you have a legacy application (non-java) that connects to a fixed port, and forces me to launch the sever on that fixed port... unfortunately.